# add table row by using specific $index using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my requirement I have to bind/display in html table using `ng-repeat` and also add row dynamically to that specific click/index. I tried, but unable to solve.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Date of Initiation</th>
    <th>Change Control Number</th>
    <th>Manufacturing Unit</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Owner Name</th>
    <th>QA Contact Name</th>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Status of Progress</th>
    <th>Regulatory Category</th>
    <th>Documents Effected</th>
    <th>Target Closure Date</th>
    <th>Actual Closure Date</th>
    <th>Change Implementation Date</th>
    <th>Comments/Cross References</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="rowIndex_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="ccms in CCMSResData track by $index">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Id}}" value="{{ccms.Id}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Initiation_Date}}" value="{{ccms.Initiation_Date}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Change_Control_Number}}" value="{{ccms.Change_Control_Number}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Manufacturing_Unit}}" value="{{ccms.Manufacturing_Unit}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Department}}" value="{{ccms.Department}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Product_Name}}" value="{{ccms.Product_Name}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Change_Title}}" value="{{ccms.Change_Title}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Description_Change}}" value="{{ccms.Description_Change}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Owner_Name}}" value="{{ccms.Owner_Name}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Qa_Contact_Name}}" value="{{ccms.Qa_Contact_Name}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Product_Code}}" value="{{ccms.Product_Code}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Progress_Status}}" value="{{ccms.Progress_Status}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Reportable_Category}}" value="{{ccms.Reportable_Category}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Documents_Effected}}" value="{{ccms.Documents_Effected}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Target_Closure_Date}}" value="{{ccms.Target_Closure_Date}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Actual_Closure_Date}}" value="{{ccms.Actual_Closure_Date}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Change_Implementation_Date}}" value="{{ccms.Change_Implementation_Date}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ccms.Comments_Cross_References}}" value="{{ccms.Comments_Cross_References}}"></td>
```

```
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" 
           title="Add" ng-click="addCCMSDataClick($index,ccms.Product_Name)"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip"
           title="Delete"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
cm.addCCMSDataClick = function(index, productName) {
  cm.CCMSResData.push(index, {
    "val": "1"
  })
};
```

Comment: What happens when you console.log() in `addCCMSDataClick` do you get desired value? Seems like probably dont have correct scope available at the binding site `ng-click` because you are within the scope of individual `ng-repeat` item

Comment: If we click addCCMSDataClick i am getting row index and product name now i want to add a new row at bottom to that particular row index and productname

Comment: Based on what you have seems like you are trying to push something at the same index as previous item was. Also `CCMSResData` seems Array which only takes value item not index. May be your need is to remove index and just add `{ desiredObj }`

Comment: my need is just add one empty table row at bottom of the particular row index when we click on add icon.

Comment: Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to add to an array by index.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you need. You need to add all the missing properties in that object.

```js
cm.addCCMSDataClick = function(index, productName) {
  cm.CCMSResData.push({
    "Initiation_Date": "",
    "Change_Control_Number": "",
    .
    .
    .
    "Change_Implementation_Date": "",
    "Comments_Cross_References": ""
  })
};
```

Based on OP, he wants to add row right after the index passed in i.e. in between array items. So solution for that would be to use `splice` instead.

```js
cm.addCCMSDataClick = function(index, productName) {
  cm.CCMSResData.splice(index, 0, {
    "Initiation_Date": "",
    "Change_Control_Number": "",
    .
    .
    .
    "Change_Implementation_Date": "",
    "Comments_Cross_References": ""
  })
};
```

Comment: First you understand my requirement : I have a table where i will add dynamic table rows . So when i click on a particular row then the row should add for that particular table row below. as per the attached code when i try to add/click a row then the new row is adding in the last row/bottom  of the table. please suggest us

Comment: Well that is based on my understanding of your issue which is to add one more item in an Array upon click of `+` sign. If that's not the case please clarify your question and what exactly is not working.

Comment: @chaitanay based on your structure, you have exactly 1 Table, with 19 columns in a row repeating in ng-repeat times. If your intention is to add a row in between rows, i.e. Assuming you clicked on `+` icon on the second row and you want to add row right between second and third row, you want to shift all the rows from index = 2 (0 based indexing) to the end and move one place to the right. Is that what you want? If so you are potentially looking for `splice` method